# Laravel DataTable - $dataTable is undefined

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, metronic

I created a Model, Controller, Factory and dataTable files, but laravel keeps showing me the error `$dataTable is undefined`

How come? Is it a routing issue or I'm not linking the controller to the blade correctly?

**My controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DataTables\DataEntry\ReportsDataTable;

class ReportsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(ReportsDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render("pages.dataEntry.reports.index");
    }
}
```

**The Route:**

```
// Data Entry pages
    Route::prefix('dataEntry')->name('dataEntry.')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('reports', ReportsController::class)->only(['index']);
    });
```

**index.blade:**

```
<x-base-layout>

    <!--begin::Card-->
    <div class="card">
        <!--begin::Card body-->
        <div class="card-body pt-6">
            <!--begin::Table-->
             {{ $dataTable->table() }}
            <!--end::Table-->

            {{-- Inject Scripts --}}
             {{ $dataTable->scripts() }}
        </div>
        <!--end::Card body-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Card-->

</x-base-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    return ReportsDataTable::all()->render("pages.dataEntry.reports.index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, still didn't work